# Exclude current object in foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach, collision-detection

So I basically want to detect collisions between two objects of the same class. I have this in my Main class to call an update function:

```
foreach (Ball i in Ball.Pool) i.update();
```

Within the update function I wrote the following collision detection:

```
foreach(Ball i in Pool)
{
    if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(i.pos.X - pos.X, 2) + Math.Pow(i.pos.Y - pos.Y, 2)) < 50)
    {
        //do intesect procedure
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that it is intersecting with itself all the time.

Is there some way to exclude the current object from the foreach loop?

Comment: Why not just check if the two objects are equal? That way you won't compare the ball with itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an equality check:

```
foreach(Ball i in Pool)
{
    if(i <> this)
        if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(i.pos.X - pos.X, 2) + Math.Pow(i.pos.Y - pos.Y, 2)) < 50)
        {
            //do intesect procedure
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ:

```
foreach (var ball in Pool.Where(b => b != currentBall)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply check if you `ball` in `foreach` is the same as "current Ball" by using `==`. To skip iteration of the loop - use `continue` which immediately starts next iteration of a loop:

```
foreach(Ball ball in Pool)
{ 
    if (ball == this) // assuming code is part of Ball class
    {
       continue;
    }
    // handle collisions 
    ....
}
```

Side note: try not to use `i` for non-integer loop variables as many readers of your code will automatically assume that type is `int` by convention.